# Location still the same although it's moved

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, objects, bones

I am using the tail location of my bone to calculate a certain distance. So I get the location of the pose bone head then I move the bone to another location and get the new location. But then the two locations are the same. The weird thing is that this only happens if I run the below script from the text editor. But if I run it from the console the difference in location is not zero, which is correct. Not sure why?

As shown below this is what is printed in the system console where the tail location is the same:[image]

while this is what happens if I print using blender's python console:
[image]

My blend file can be found here: [image]

My script included in the blend file:

```
import bpy

myarm = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
myarm.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = myarm
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')
b = myarm.pose.bones['Bone']
bOrigLoc = b.tail
print(bOrigLoc)
con = b.constraints.new('COPY_LOCATION')
con.target = bpy.data.objects['Empty']
bNewLoc = b.tail
print(bNewLoc)
```

I've tried using objects as well instead of bones and still the same problem although the object is moved it still gives the same location:

```
import bpy

myarm = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
myarm.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = myarm
OrigLoc = myarm.matrix_world.to_translation()
print(OrigLoc)
myarm.location = bpy.data.objects['Empty'].location
NewLoc = myarm.matrix_world.to_translation()
print(NewLoc)
```

Comment: Update your scene once the copy location constraint is added: bpy.context.scene.update()

Comment: Perhaps using the py console triggers a scene update (my guess is for each statement) , whereas the script doesn't.  Consider a `scene.update()`

Comment: @lemon thank you very much, that was the issue

Comment: @batFINGER yes, you are correct, as lemon mentioned as well, updating the scene was the problem